# SQL Server Management Studio Unexpected results

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

If I compile the Storedprocedure in **Tab1**, and If I'm executing the SP by giving the parameter in **Tab2** in same SSMS, the results are totally unexpected.

I'm login into SSMS by Windows Authentication.

That would be great, If somebody provide the trouble shooting points for this kind of issue.

Example:

Opened the SSMS and loging in as WindowAuthentication User
**Client TABLE**

```
ClientID ClientName  
1          A  
2          B  
3          C  
5          D
4          E  
0          A1
```

**Tab 1 Has the below code

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE [ClientNames]
(
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Client 
END -- End of the Procedure
```

Tab 2 has the below code

```
EXEC    [dbo].[RT_GetRIsExcludedFromMetricsReport]
```

**Result**

```
ClientID ClientName  
1          A  
2          B  
3          C  
5          D
4          E  
0          A1
```

Now Closing the SSMS and loging in as WindowAuthentication User
Again Opened the SSMS
**Client TABLE**

```
ClientID ClientName  
1          A  
2          B  
3          C  
5          D
4          E  
0          A1
```

**Tab1 Has the below code

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE [ClientNames]
(
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Client 
         **Order by ClientID -- Changed the Query**
END
```

**Tab 2 has the below code**

**EXEC  [dbo].[RT_GetRIsExcludedFromMetricsReport]**

**Expected Result**

```
ClientID ClientName  
0          A1**
1          A  
2          B  
3          C  
4          E    
5          D
```

**But Results showing as**
**Result**

```
ClientID ClientName  
1          A  
2          B  
3          C  
5          D
4          E  
0          A1
```

Comment: Try posting code and/or giving a clear scenario to reproduce your problem. This is too vague for us to really help.

Comment: Why are you not using the schema prefix on `ClientNames` and `Client`? Is it possible you're seeing unexpected results because you have two different versions of the stored procedure? Please read: https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix ... my guess is that one user is calling a procedure in `dbo`, with an order by, and the other is calling a procedure with the same name in a different schema, and that procedure doesn't have the order by.

Comment: If you don't have a duplicate as Aaron suggested and you execute DBCC FREEPROCCACHE and then do your EXEC again, do you get the expected result? **NOTE:** Don't do this in production, it clears the plan cache for all stored proceures.